# Efficient way to upload manipulated images to S3 from a URL with angular or PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, amazon-s3, upload

I have an application where users can upload photos. Photos go directly to an Amazon S3 bucket. After they've been uploaded, I need to let them crop and resize the images from the S3 bucket whenever they want.

Right now I'm downloading the image to my server, performing the crop and resize functions with codeigniter, sending the newly manipulated image to the S3 bucket, and then deleting the image from my server.

Is there a better way to do this without downloading the image to the server to perform the manipulations?

Comment: This is really, really broad. Can you narrow?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Sure can! I just edited it. Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize how stupidly broad I'd made the question.